# Virtual Pascal RunTime Error (or no output) if including Printer unit?

Tags: pascal

I'm using Virtual Pascal on Windows and have a weird problem whereby if an attempt to `Reset()` any file that doesn't exist causes the `WriteLn()` to CRT fail.  Example:

```
{$I+}
program TestIt;

uses Printer; { attempts to open LPT1 as Lst but LPT1 doesn't exist on system }

begin
  { Generates a RunTime Error with $I+ and no output with $I- }
  writeln('Test It');
end.
```

This also fails:

```
program TestIt;

var
  SomeFile : text;
begin
{$I-} 
  Assign(SomeFile, 'a:\filepath_not_exist');
  { Without $I- the Reset generates a RunTime Error as expected }
  Reset(SomeFile);
{$I+}
  { Generates a RunTime Error with $I+ and no output with $I- }
  writeln('Test It');
end.
```

This works as expected:

```
{$I+}
program TestIt;

begin
  writeln('Test It');
end.
```

Any ideas why this may be happening and how to fix it?  Is the source available for `WriteLn()` or `Assign()` ?  I'm able to change the `Printer` unit to not `Reset()` to work around it until needing to get printing working but I don't think failure to open a file should cause the screen output to stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the error state is kept in some variable (which is queried by ioresult) and might cause an error to be raised in the next I/O function. If you don't do automatic error checking ($I+) you must call ioresult after every operation.

Such implementation is not ideal (if errors from the opening using "somefile" spill into a writeln to a second(output) file as happens in the second example), but it happens, specially in older compilers, and specially on targets that are less dos-like.

Also, not existing drive errors are much harder to cache than non existing files. Keep those cases fundamentally apart.

You can test this theory by trying to reset state by querying ioresult just before the action in the hope it resets the state.

Afaik VP is dead for almost a decade now. What you see (read: download) is what you get.

Comment: I'll try to dig in to it.  I've already fixed ClrEOL (Needed +1 for X,Y FastFill), RestoreCursorState (Lo/Hi for Scanlines was backwards), and Cursor Update handling through an event thread that was not threadsafe (and added a clean up if SysCtrlEnterCritSec was used).  I'd consider FreePascal since maintained, but I don't like the NCurses Requirement. Delphi maybe but would have to adjust for different crt unit handling of windows console.

Comment: Yes, ioresult clears it so it works - I supposed that is how it's supposed to work, it must have just never come up because in DOS environment LPT1 exists  and no other io errors when {$I-} was used.

Comment: Free Pascal has no ncurses requirement on non *nix.  Delphi is increasingly fragmented between old, and new but with horribly expensive purchase+ mandatory subscription.

Comment: Thanks, It was GNU pascal that had that requirement - I see it listed as GNU Pascal - Free Pascal so assumed it was the same but it's not.   I'll have to check out Free Pascal's CRT support for Borland (FastWrite, FastWriteWindow, etc..).

Comment: So why not give Free Pascal a go? GPC and VP haven't had releases in a decade, and worse there are no real support options anymore.